# The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

My microservice doesn't run in Docker, even when the dependencies are present in specified folder `'lib/netstandard2.0/Ben.Demystifier.dll'` Kindly suggest.

Error:

> An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest
>   (Service.deps.json) was not found:
>       package: 'Ben.Demystifier', version: '0.1.4'
>       path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Ben.Demystifier.dll' The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target
>   process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the
>   target process did not run on .NET Core. The program 'dotnet' has
>   exited with code 140 (0x8c).

Comment: Can you show how you are starting this application? And; is it a dotnet core assembly or .net standard?

Comment: I'm running application from VS2019, clicking on Docker profile. Application is using Microsoft.AspNetCore.All.dll